# How to check if an object is visible in front of the camera?

Tags: camera, viewport, godot, gdscript, godot4

I would be grateful if you could suggest a way for me to check if the object is being rendered or not.
Thanks.

I try to use "VisibleOnScreenNotifier3D" Node. But for example, if the object is placed behind the wall (MeshInstance3D), the "screen_exited" signal will not be called.

Comment: You need to start by recognizing that ti is not binary. The object can be fully visible, partially visible with varying degree, or not visible at all. Then your solution will depend on how precise and how fast you need the measurement to be. On one end you have doing a raycast from the camera to the object, but that only checks one point (or multiple with multiple raycasts) and it is actually checking physics not graphics. On the other end you have rendering the object to a secondary viewport and comparing pixels, but that is more computationally expensive.

Comment: I finally managed to do it with the help of camera frustum culling and raycast together. Of course, the detection accuracy is low in some positions, but I am satisfied. Thanks